# Use of the adverb first in conjunction with then

Tags: word-choice, grammar, adverbs, word-order

Are the use and the positions of the adverbs *first* and *then* correct in the following two sentences?

> We prove, first, two preliminary properties, and, then, the whole theorem.
>
> We first show the formula, and then prove that its value is positive.

If the sentences are incorrect, or if they do not flow smoothly, how could they be fixed or improved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Too many commas — old-fashioned. Try:

*We prove **first** two preliminary properties **and then** the whole theorem.*

***First[,]*** we prove two preliminary properties **and then** the whole theorem.

You don't need comma before "and," as these are not independent clauses (they have the same subject, "we").

e.g.,

> CRM Proceedings & Lecture Notes - Volumes 14-15 - Page 131 John P.
>   Harnad, ‎Alex Kasman - 1998 -
>
> ... rigidity theorems, **we solve** for harmonic spinors which have the
>   correct behavior at infinity **and then** integrate by parts. ... To prove
>   Theorem 2, **we prove first** the existence of a harmonic spinor which is
>   asymptotically parallel in the sense that ...